# ninject Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.Filter.FilterContextParameter' in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a mvc4 web application. I decided to use ninject.mvc3. so I installed it from nuget. But it is throwing this exception:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.Filter.FilterContextParameter'. Derived types must
>   either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less
>   accessible.

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
      {
          var kernel = new StandardKernel(); //Throws exception this line
          kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
          kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
          return kernel;
      }
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? Or does anyone have any ideas how to track down what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help if you add the following line to your AssemblyInfo.cs file with a reference to the System.Web.Security namespace?.

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]
```